# Python Selenium : How to extract a text value from the HTML

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

With Python and Selenium, I try to extract a text value from a website.
Extract of HTML :

```html
<div order=2" class="css-1asuq02 e1y0u4b10">
<p>
<span role="img" aria-label="icon-circle" class="css-shla5t ef02kcv0">
</span>
"343 W"
</p>
</div>
```

Python code:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value= ???)
```

I tried :

```py
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, value='//div[@order="2"]')
```

It works but too many elements

How to select ONLY this `order="2"` and class (Xpath, contains, other) ?

I want to retrieve 343 value

Answer (score 0):

To print the text ***343 W*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[order='2'] > p").text)
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@order='2']/p").text)
  ```

---

To extract the text ***343 W*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[order='2'] > p"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@order='2']/p"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)